# Function triggering in jquery?

Tags: jquery

In My jquery function i used to trigger click function from li and img seperately but 
unfortunately when i click image. Click function for list also triggers

**HTML CODE:**

```
  <li id="list_id">List_text<img src='image.jpg' id="img_id"></li>
```

**Jquery function:**

```
$("#list_id").click(function(){
 alert('List is clicked');
});

$("#img_id").click(function(){
 alert('Image is clicked');
});
```

Once i click image both function triggers.

****Question:****I need to trigger only click function for image once i click image and to trigger click function for list once i click list

Comment: i somewhere read stopPropagation is better than return false ,i will get you the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [stop the event propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$("#img_id").click(function(evt){
    alert('Image is clicked');
    evt.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Still it calls li click function. Since i get li and img from ajax. i think its not working

Comment: What do you mean that you are getting li and img from AJAX? When do you attach the click handler? And here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P6vgS/).

Answer (score 0):

use   event.stopPropagation();

```
     $("#img_id").click(function(){
             alert('Image is clicked');
  event.stopPropagation();
            });
```

Comment: Still it calls li click function. Since i get li and img from ajax. i think its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#img_id").click(function(){
  alert('Image is clicked');
  return false;
});
```

Just return `false` from the function, which will [prevent the event from bubbling up](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#event-object) (among preventing other default actions, if that's what you want).

Comment: stopPropagation is better than return false as it kills all the futured...events for that

Comment: @gov Depends on what exactly the OP wants, added a note to my answer.